# Is Complement of a Dense Open Subset in R Perfect?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

I have been self studying Classical Analysis by TBB. I stumbled on this exercise problem which I think may not be right. I am not sure what I am missing or the gap in my understanding. Here it goes.

Let $G$ be a dense open subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and let $\{(a_k, b_k)\}$ be its component intervals. Prove that $H = G^c = \mathbb{R}\G$ is perfect if and only if not two of these intervals have common end-points.

Here are my observations.

1. If $G$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ then we can write it as a union of disjoint intervals. I am assuming that is just redundant information.
2. If $G = \bigcup_0^\infty (i, i+1) \cup (-i-1, -i) : \ i \in \mathbb{N}$, clearly $G$ is an open set. It is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, but $G^c$ is not perfect.

I am attaching an image of the original problem as well. What am I missing?[image]

Comment: The answer to your **title** is no. Your title omits an important part of the actual question: **"no two of these intervals have common end-points."**

Comment: If two of the component intervals have a common end point, you will have an isolated point in $G^c$, meaning it isn't perfect. Meanwhile, if no two component intervals have a common end point, then for any $x \in G^c$, you can take an interval $I \subset G^c$ containing $x$, meaning $x$ isn't isolated, meaning G^c has no isolated points. Therefore since the complement of an open set is closed, $G^c$ is perfect.

Comment: @Joe, So common end point would mean that (0,1) (1,0) counts as intervals with common end point? That is not how I interpreted it. Thank you.

Comment: @bof, yes that was a typo, thanks for pointing it out. I have fixed it.

Comment: @RameshKadambi No, that's EXACTLY what would count as a common endpoint. That would lead to $1$ being an isolated point in the compliment.

Comment: @Joe, Got it you responded before I fixed my error. Thanks.

Comment: @RameshKadambi Ahh yeah, if you didn't interpret it that way the problem totally changes. Happy to help.

Comment: I wouldn't count "$(0,1),(1,0)$" as intervals with a common endpoint, but I would count $(0,1),(1,2)$ as such.

Comment: @Joe The hypotheses don't imply that any $x\in G^c$ lies in a non-degenerate interval $I\subseteq G^c$. For example, $G$ might consist of the intervals $(\frac1{2n+1},\frac1{2n})$ for all positive integers $n$ and the interval $(-1,0)$, and $x$ might be $0$. Then $0\in G^c$ but every non-degenerate interval containing $0$ also contains points from $G$. (Nevertheless, as the problem claims, $0$ is not isolated in $G^c$.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass Ahh very fair point -- I hadn't considered that. In my head I had assumed finitely many intervals to $G$ which clearly need not be the case.

Comment: @bof, yep that is kind of what I had in mind. I understand, the example I gave as counter example does not qualify, since there are intervals that share end points. Thanks again to all.